# VBA Transpose Multiple Array with more than 255 Characters

Tags: vba, excel

I've tried a number of different ways, but cannot figure it out.  And the similar posts haven't helped me because I have never done this before, but I have multiple arrays I need to transpose due to having more than 255 characters.  Below are my arrays.

```
Sub Quick()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
Dim Target As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim FormulaR1C1

FormulaR1C1 = getR1C1Array
Set Target = Range("A1:ZZ1").Find("LiquidD")

If Not Target Is Nothing Then
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set Target = Target.Offset(1).Resize(UBound(FormulaR1C1, 1), UBound(FormulaR1C1, 2))
    Target.FormulaR1C1 = FormulaR1C1
    Set Target = Target.Rows(Target.Rows.Count).Resize(lastRow - Target.Rows.Count)
    Target.Rows(1).AutoFill Destination:=Target
    'Uncomment to replace worksheet formulas with their value for better performance
    'Target.EntireColumn.Value = Target.EntireColumn.Value
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Function getR1C1Array()
Dim data
ReDim data(6)
data(0) = Array("=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]", "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]/6", "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]/14", "=IF(AND(R[1048574]C[-18]=RC[-18],COUNTIF(RC[-9]:R[1048574]C[-9],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-9]:R[1048574]C[-9]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048574]C[-19]=RC[-19], COUNTIF(RC[-9]:R[1048574]C[-9],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-9]:R[1048574]C[-9]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048574]C[-20]=RC[-20],COUNTIF(RC[-9]:R[1048574]C[-9],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-9]:R[1048574]C[-9]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-21]=RC[-21],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-22]=RC[-22],COUNTIF(RC[6]:R[1048571]C[6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[6]:R[1048571]C[6]),0)", "=IF(R[1048571]C[-23]=RC[-23],AVERAGE(RC[6]:R[1048571]C[6]),0)", "=(INTERCEPT(RC[-11]:R[-5]C[-11],RC[-15]:R[-5]C[-15])+(RC[-15]*SLOPE(RC[-11]:R[5]C[-11],RC[-15]:R[5]C[-15])))-RC[-11]", "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,IF(RC[-1]>RC[-11],0,1))", "=IF(RC[-1]=1,RC[-11],0)", "=0", "=0")
data(1) = Array("=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]", "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]/6", "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]/14", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-18]=RC[-18],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-9]:RC[-9],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-9]:RC[-9]),0)", "=IF(R[-2]C[-19]=RC[-19],AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-9]:RC[-9]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-20]=RC[-20],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-9]:RC[-9],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-9]:RC[-9]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-21]=RC[-21],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[-1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-22]=RC[-22],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-23]=RC[-23],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=(INTERCEPT(R[-1]C[-11]:R[4]C[-11],R[-1]C[-15]:R[4]C[-15])+(RC[-15]*SLOPE(R[-1]C[-11]:R[4]C[-11],R[-1]C[-15]:R[4]C[-15])))-RC[-11]", "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,IF(RC[-1]>RC[-11],0,1))", "=IF(RC[-1]=1,RC[-11],0)", "=0", "=0")
data(2) = Array("=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]", "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]/6", "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]/14", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-18]=RC[-18],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(R[-2]C[-19]=RC[-19],AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-20]=RC[-20],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-21]=RC[-21],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[-1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-22]=RC[-22],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-23]=RC[-23],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=(INTERCEPT(R[-2]C[-11]:R[3]C[-11],R[-2]C[-15]:R[3]C[-15])+(RC[-15]*SLOPE(R[-2]C[-11]:R[3]C[-11],R[-2]C[-15]:R[3]C[-15])))-RC[-11]", "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,IF(RC[-1]>RC[-11],0,1))", "=IF(RC[-1]=1,RC[-11],0)", "=0", "=0")
data(3) = Array("=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]", "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]/6", "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]/14", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-18]=RC[-18],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(R[-2]C[-19]=RC[-19],AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-20]=RC[-20],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-21]=RC[-21],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[-1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-22]=RC[-22],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[1048571]C[-23]=RC[-23],COUNTIF(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(RC[-6]:R[1048571]C[-6]),0)", "=(INTERCEPT(R[-3]C[-11]:R[2]C[-11],R[-3]C[-15]:R[2]C[-15])+(RC[-15]*SLOPE(R[-3]C[-11]:R[2]C[-11],R[-3]C[-15]:R[2]C[-15])))-RC[-11]", "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,IF(RC[-1]>RC[-11],0,1))", "=IF(RC[-1]=1,RC[-11],0)", "=0", "=0")
data(4) = Array("=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]", "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]/6", "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]/14", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-18]=RC[-18],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(R[-2]C[-19]=RC[-19],AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-20]=RC[-20],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-21]=RC[-21],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-22]=RC[-22],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-23]=RC[-23],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=(INTERCEPT(R[-3]C[-11]:R[2]C[-11],R[-3]C[-15]:R[2]C[-15])+(RC[-15]*SLOPE(R[-3]C[-11]:R[2]C[-11],R[-3]C[-15]:R[2]C[-15])))-RC[-11]", "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,IF(RC[-1]>RC[-11],0,1))", "=IF(RC[-1]=1,RC[-11],0)", "=0", "=0")
data(5) = Array("=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]", "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]/6", "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]/14", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-18]=RC[-18],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(R[-2]C[-19]=RC[-19],AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-20]=RC[-20],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-21]=RC[-21],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-22]=RC[-22],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-23]=RC[-23],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=(INTERCEPT(R[-3]C[-11]:R[2]C[-11],R[-3]C[-15]:R[2]C[-15])+(RC[-15]*SLOPE(R[-3]C[-11]:R[2]C[-11],R[-3]C[-15]:R[2]C[-15])))-RC[-11]", "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,IF(RC[-1]>RC[-11],0,1))", "=IF(RC[-1]=1,RC[-11],0)", "=0", "=0")
data(6) = Array("=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]/DAY(EOMONTH(RC[-2],0))", "=RC[-2]", "=RC[-3]+RC[-2]/6", "=RC[-4]+RC[-3]/14", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-18]=RC[-18],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(R[-2]C[-19]=RC[-19],AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-2]C[-20]=RC[-20],COUNTIF(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-2]C[-3]:RC[-3]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-21]=RC[-21],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-22]=RC[-22],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=IF(AND(R[-5]C[-23]=RC[-23],COUNTIF(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6],0)=0),AVERAGE(R[-5]C[-6]:RC[-6]),0)", "=(INTERCEPT(R[-3]C[-11]:R[2]C[-11],R[-3]C[-15]:R[2]C[-15])+(RC[-15]*SLOPE(R[-3]C[-11]:R[2]C[-11],R[-3]C[-15]:R[2]C[-15])))-RC[-11]", "=IF(RC[-11]=0,0,IF(RC[-1]>RC[-11],0,1))", "=IF(RC[-1]=1,RC[-11],0)", "=0", "=0")
End Function

Function getFormulaR1C1Array(Source As Range)
Dim r As Range
Dim Result As String
Result = "Array("
For Each r In Source
    Result = Result & Chr(34) & Replace(r.FormulaR1C1, Chr(34), Chr(34) & Chr(34)) & Chr(34) & ","
Next

Result = Left(Result, Len(Result) - 1) & ")"

getFormulaR1C1Array = Result

End Function
```

Currently there are no strings longer than 255 characters, b/c I've been working on them separately until I can figure out how to transpose them.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I ran into this issue and ended up having to loop through a range set and dump each array item into the range using a counter and range.offset for each cell.value. I am sure it can be modified for formula just as well.

Comment: Is it possible you could provide an example? I'm not too familiar with ranges in vba.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how I worked around the issue when I came across it recently. I included the entire procedure so you can see how the arrays are being populated, but the meat of the workaround I used is in last part of code `With wsStaging`.

In this case `arrSubjectivity` is populated by cells, some of which had > 255 characters of text.

```
Sub StageSubjectivities()

sProcName = "StageSubjectivities"

With wsSubjectivities

    Dim lRow As Long
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Range("subjectivity_list").Column).END(xlUp).Row

    Dim rSubjectivity As Range

    For Each rSubjectivity In .Range(.Cells(.Range("subjectivity_list").Row + 2, 1), .Cells(lRow, 1))

        If rSubjectivity.Value = "X" Then

            Dim arrLOB() As Variant
            Dim arrSubjectivity() As Variant

            Dim iCnt As Integer
            ReDim Preserve arrLOB(iCnt)
            ReDim Preserve arrSubjectivity(iCnt)

            arrLOB(iCnt) = rSubjectivity.Offset(, 9)
            arrSubjectivity(iCnt) = rSubjectivity.Offset(, 1)

            iCnt = iCnt + 1

        End If

    Next

End With

With wsStaging
    Range(.Range("SubjectivityList").Offset(2), .Range("SubjectivityList").Offset(2).END(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Clear 'first it will clear the range and fill again
    .Range("SubjectivityList").Offset(2).Resize(UBound(arrLOB) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrLOB)
    'The below line errors out because of text > 255 not working with Array Transpose
    '.Range("SubjectivityList").Offset(2).Resize(UBound(arrSubjectivity) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrSubjectivity)
    'iCnt declared above to use as a counter
    For iCnt = 0 To UBound(arrSubjectivity)
        With .Range("SubjectivityList").Offset(iCnt + 2, 1)
            .Value = arrSubjectivity(iCnt)
            .WrapText = False 'because sometimes it wraps text aotmatically
        End With
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Okay, so I updated my code.  Just to confirm your first part of the Sub, "With wsSubjectivities" is basically my, "Function getR1C1Array()" is that correct? Then, how does your, "With wsStaging" know what your Range is, "SubjectivityList"? I guess what I'm asking is which part of my code is useful and which part do I need to replace/modify since I have characters longer than 255?

Comment: Does your SubjectivityList represent the worksheet your on?

Comment: `SubjectivityList` in `wsStaging` is just a placeholder cell where I store the information (since that sheet is used for several staging processes (think ETL).

Comment: If you have a minute could  you please add some comments to the code? One thing I'm trying to figure out is how to incorporate my, getR1C1Array function into this sub proc.  My thought process is that after I modify your code I will need it to read in my arrays, "getR1C1Array",  transpose it then run it through my Function, "getFormulaR1C1Array", and finally through my sub proc, "Quick".  Also, I've yet to use With statements, so that's another reason for getting confused.